# Error in library(mxnet) : there is no package called ‘mxnet’

Tags: r, classification, mxnet

I started my mxnet package installation for R in ubuntu with the following command

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("mxnet")
```

while executing this command I got the following warning

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mxnet’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

Then I went for the command

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet",dependencies = T)
```

At that time I got the warning

```
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘mxnet’ failed
```

For the first time I got installed the package ,but when I calling `library(mxnet)` I got the waring Error in `library(mxnet) : there is no package called ‘mxnet’`.After that I tried the same command above again ,at that time I got this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
      download of package ‘mxnet’ failed
```

Please help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Download the mxnet.zip file to a folder, set it as working directory and then run:

install.packages("mxnet.zip", repos=NULL, type="win.binary")

Comment: I am using ubuntu..I getting the  following error while using the above command.

Error in install.packages : cannot install Windows binary packages on this platform

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install like this:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git mxnet
cd mxnet/docs/install
./install_mxnet_ubuntu_python.sh
./install_mxnet_ubuntu_r.sh
```

More details in the comment.

Comment: http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/ubuntu_setup.html#install-the-mxnet-package-for-r

Comment: I tried this code also..But after that also I am getting the same error..

Error in library(mxnet) : there is no package called ‘mxnet’

Comment: Hard luck mate! Hopefully someone else helps you solve your problem. I successfully installed it on my side. What hapens before you call `library(mxnet)`? Did the package install or not? Maybe check your internet? Or do a manual download of the package?